# apache mod_write RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Doesn't works

Tags: proxy, apache

I am trying to redirecto to other machine by filtering the user agent in a apache web server. I have a web server in the machine with the ip 192.168.2.11, but this web server only should send the page to the requests WITHOUT this user agent:

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20

Instead it should redirect the request to 192.168.1.40 that have other web server running.

I tried to modify the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf with the next code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://192.168.1.40 [L,R=302]
```

But doesn't work, it always show index.html from the 192.168.2.11 machine (it doesnt redirect). Why? How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I think I'm indicating wrong the user_agent because this works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${HTTP_USER_AGENT} Ubuntu
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

So the question is, how can I specify a particular user_agent? and how can I spacify all user_agent exept that particular user_agent?

Comment: You should add a backreference in the rewrite rule like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://192.168.1.40/$1 [L,R=302]`
This may not solve the entire issue as the redirect is still not working!, but this is required.

Comment: It still always show the 192.168.2.11 main page, but thanks man!

Comment: You have to put these few lines in your virtual host config. For instance in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, not in the main config file. This config worked for me. Beware of the default behaviour of your browser which may switch to https.

Comment: I have in the 000-default.conf the lines to redirect http to https (and those work fine), but I've tried to put both fragments code in the question in the 000-default and in the desfault-ssl and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation of the RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), you can use either regular expressions or plain string

> ... CondPattern is usually a perl compatible regular expression, but there is additional syntax available to perform other useful tests against the Teststring: ...

So, in order to rewrite for any user agent except this one "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20", you have to use the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20"
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://192.168.1.40/$1 [L,R=302]
```

You can also combine multiple `RewriteCond` for the same `RewriteRule`. But this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Note the `%` sign instead of `$` in `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}`

Comment: But if I what not just to redirect the ubuntu requests, but also that have this specific user agent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20", how can I do it? I mean, If in the command you told me replace *buntu with "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20" it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, I've got it, thacks!!